# Remove all zero-rows and zero-columns from a matrix

Tags: java

I want to remove rows and columns from a matrix if all the elements in that row/column are equal to 0.

e.g. A matrix of size 3 x 3 is as follows

> 3 5 6
>   0 0 0
>   5 6 8

The resultant matrix after removing zero rows and columns is

> 3 5 6
>   5 6 8

Note:
Input: Accept the input matrix values from Console.
Output: Print the input and output matrices on Console

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, what, and what problems do you have? I think the question might be 'Can you do my code while I go down the pub?'!

Comment: Is that a genuine problem or is it just some sort of homework assignment? You might iterate through the matrix, deleting faulty entries..

Comment: creat an 2d array, iterate over the row and remove if the sum is 0. then iterate over the columns and if the sum is null remove all elements. in an array you cant remove them you have to replace them with an default. if you really want to remove them, use and List<List<int>>

Comment: @kai: what if the elements are -1, -1 and 2?

Comment: my fault. set a boolean to false if one of the items is != 0

Comment: I think you provided useful info on 2d List declaration though, so +1 for that @kai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not the most efficient way, but I think it somewhat didatic :-)

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CleanIt {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
//      double[][] matrix = readFromConsole(System.in);
        String input = "3\n3\n1 0 2\n0 0 0\n3 0 4\n";
        double[][] matrix = read(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes("UTF-8")));

        write(matrix,System.out);
        double[][] rowsCleaned = cleanZeroRows(matrix);
        write(rowsCleaned,System.out);
        double[][] transposed = transpose(rowsCleaned);
        write(transposed,System.out);
        double[][] colsCleaned = cleanZeroRows(transposed);
        write(colsCleaned,System.out);
        double[][] transposedBack = transpose(colsCleaned);
        write(transposedBack,System.out);
    }

    private static double[][] cleanZeroRows(double[][] matrix) {
        //first find those that need to delete
        boolean[] deleteThese = new boolean[matrix.length];
        int count = 0;

        int rows = matrix.length;
        int cols = matrix[0].length;
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
            boolean allZeros = true;
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
                if (matrix[i][j] != 0){
                    allZeros = false;
                    break;
                }
            }           
            deleteThese[i] = allZeros;
            if (allZeros){
                count++;
            }
        }

        //
        if (count == 0){
            return matrix;
        }else if (count == matrix.length){
            return new double[0][0];
        }else{
            double[][] newMatrix = new double[rows - count][cols];
            int idx = -1;
            for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
                if (!deleteThese[i]){
                    idx++;
                    newMatrix[idx] = matrix[i];
                }
            }
            return newMatrix;
        }
    }

    /**
     * expects N\nM\ne1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7...
     * @param in 
     * @return
     */
    private static double[][] read(InputStream in) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
        int rows = scan.nextInt();
        int cols = scan.nextInt();
        double[][] matrix = new double[rows][cols];
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
                matrix[i][j] = scan.nextDouble();
            }           
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    private static void write(double[][] matrix, PrintStream out) {
        int rows = matrix.length;
        int cols = matrix[0].length;
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
                out.print(matrix[i][j]);
                out.print(" ");
            }           
            out.print("\n");
        }
        out.print("\n");
    }

    public static double[][] transpose(double[][] m) {
        int r = m.length;
        int c = m[0].length;
        double[][] t = new double[c][r];
        for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
                t[j][i] = m[i][j];
            }
        }
        return t;
    }

}
```

output is

```
1.0 0.0 2.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
3.0 0.0 4.0 

1.0 0.0 2.0 
3.0 0.0 4.0 

1.0 3.0 
0.0 0.0 
2.0 4.0 

1.0 3.0 
2.0 4.0 

1.0 2.0 
3.0 4.0
```

Comment: Certainly it works. But my whole Tetris clone has less code than your code only to remove a line! :D

Comment: and tetris is way more fun too :-)